# How to write two class for single id in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have button with ID "searchBtn". Each time the button is clicked, the class should change. I want to rotate through a predefined number of classes on each click.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I don't really understand this question, but perhaps jQuery's `.addClass()`, `.removeClass()` and `.toggleClass()` may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try the jquery's [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchBtn').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('class_x','class_y');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give something like this a try:

```
$('#searchBtn').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('classA')) {
        $(this).removeClass('classA').addClass('classB');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('classB').addClass('classA');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#searchBtn').on('click', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('oldClass');
  $(this).addClass('newClass');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter = 0;

$("#searchBtn").click(function(){

 $(SELECTOR).removeClass("class"+counter++);
 $(SELECTOR).addClass("class"+counter);

});
```

Comment: am new to jQuery friend. why should we use counter here? can u explain it.

Comment: You mentioned shift so I thought you meant every time you clicked on the button you would want to increase your class from ".class1" to ".class2" then ".class3". Maybe I misread your question?

Comment: ya i have only two classes it should be altered on every click

Comment: Ah, I see! then Steven Farley answer is what you are looking for.